# How could I move all my files and folder to the master branch in GitHub?

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I have a GitHub repository with 2 Branches: master , engineers.
All my files and folders are in engineers branch. The master branch is empty.

I downloaded the GitHub Desktop, login using my GitHub account, then clone the project.

Now, I want to move everything in engineers branch to master branch. I follow different tutorials to merge them using GitHub Desktop. Here what I did:

1. In the GitHub Desktop client, switch to the master branch.
2. Go to Branch > Merge into Current Branch.
3. In the merge window, I select the engineers branch, and here is the problem.

I cannot do merge because I got this message `'Unable to merge unrelated history in this repository. '`

I am new to GitHub, what is the problem? What I missed? how could I move all my files and folder to the master branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your current `master` branch and then create it new from the `engineers` branch, so that you then have two branches with an identical status.

First step:

```
git checkout engineers
```

Then delete the *old* `master` branch with:

```
git branch -D master
```

Now, you have just *one* branch, which is named `engineers`. Now you can create from there a *new* branch with:

```
git branch master
```

And then navigate to this new branch:

```
git checkout master
```

You can also do this in one command:

```
git checkout -b master
```

Now you have your goal: a `master` branch with all the current files and changes as the `engineers` branch.

But be aware (like @Thomas said), the "move files" activity does not exist in Git. In Git you have ONE *main*-branch (`master`, `main` or sometimes `develop`/`dev`) and from there you create new branches and add the *code*/*file* changes from these branches (they are also called *feature-branches*, in *gitflow*) into the `main` branch with PR's or merges.

I recommend you to look at the literature to understand it!

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "moving files to another branch". Branches are not at all the same as folders. Read up on Git basics if this confuses you.

In any case: just delete the `master` branch, and create a new branch named `master` off the tip of the `engineers` branch. They will share history and essentially be the same until you commit to either of them.

On the command line, this would be:

```
git branch -D master
git branch master engineers
```

Comment: I tried that, but I got this error : Cannot delete branch ‘master’ checked out at ‘/path/to/my/github/folder’

Comment: You can‘t stay on this branch, where you want to delete. `git checkout engineers` and then remove `master`.